# How can i combine data from two mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql

I asked this question earlier but no one seemed to give me the answer i looking for so i have.

> So How can i combine data from two mysql queries where i get every
>   column or  how can i combine two mysql queries where i get every
>   column that i specified in the two queries?

QUERY 1:

```
SELECT b.id, b.post_text, c.default_photo, d.first_name, e.status 
FROM posts b 
INNER JOIN profiles c 
INNER JOIN users d 
INNER JOIN friendship e 
ON b.from_user = c.user_id 
AND b.from_user = d.id 
AND e.friend_id = b.from_user 
WHERE e.status = 'Friend' 
AND e.user_id = :id
ORDER BY b.id DESC
```

QUERY 1 Returns posts. Posts that friends posted

QUERY 2

```
SELECT b.id, b.by_who_id, b.photo_dir, c.default_photo, d.first_name, e.status
FROM photos b 
INNER JOIN profiles c 
INNER JOIN users d 
INNER JOIN follower e 
ON b.by_who_id = c.user_id 
AND b.by_who_id = d.id 
AND e.from_user = b.from_user 
WHERE e.status = 'Following' 
AND e.following_who_id = :id
ORDER BY b.id DESC
```

now QUERY 2 returns photos . if say i follow "someone" it fetches their photos

now what i want is to view a combination of posts from friends and photos from people i follow  .. how can i do this oh and im going to ORDER BY DATE by the way SO it can return

```
photo 
photo 
post 
post 
post 
photo 
post
```

no the way i might output this if its 1 query might be like

```
<?php
if ( !empty($two_queries_in_one) ) {
    foreach($two_queries_in_one as $post) :
        if ( empty($post["photo_dir"]) ) {
?>
            html here
<?php
    } else {?>
            html here

<?php } endforeach;

}
?>
```

Comment: I would ask my self: Why do you want to combine two different entities into 1 query? This will result into - in my eyes - a messy php code.

Comment: to combine the data and output with a foreach @Stefan

Comment: I suggest doing two queries and use PHP to merge them into one array.

Comment: would that do what im asking because i never used array merge before @Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can use a bit optimalisation but the idea is clear:

```
$combined = array();
foreach($query1 as $row)
{
    $combined[$row['timestamp']][] = $row; // unix timestamp in order to sort
}

foreach($query2 as $row)
{
    $combined[$row['timestamp']][] = $row; // unix timestamp in order to sort
}

ksort($combined); // sort the keys

foreach($combined as $timestamp => $rows)
{
   foreach($rows as $row)
   {
      if(isset($row['photo_dir'])
      {
         // your code for the photo 
      }
      else
      {
         // your code for the normal post
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i just noticed its a empty variable(array) lol. but what exactly does it hold inside the ksort function? does it contain everything meaning both queries?

Comment: ok so by my understanding it has all the data and it sorted it by timestamp? correct me if im wrong

Comment: You sort the array on it's key. And yes, in this case you sort the timestamp ascending.

Comment: so first it gives each item in the array a key of their time stamp right then with ksort it sorts them and then output is ready ?

Comment: one other thing the only time you specify  `=> $rows` is when the array has a key right , if the array doesn't have a key then it would be just `$combined as $timestamp`

Comment: It always has a key; with `foreach($array as $key => $value)` you are able to extract the value of the key it self. In this case the timestamp.

Comment: i mean that when you, use `foreach($array as $key => $value)` that means its an associative array and when you dont specify `=> $value` then no more associative array right?

Comment: The type of array doesnt matter. `foreach($array as $value)` gives the same result as `foreach($array as $key => $value)` but without the key.

Comment: stefan last question so then i dont need the inner foreach($rows as $row) i can just use that if statement without that inner foreach?

Comment: You need in this case the foreach because `$combined[$row['timestamp']]` is an array as well. If you don't do that then you have the possibility to miss data when two posts are done at the same timestamp.

Comment: Yes. And if you want to play a bit with the possibilities just try it and see the result of the code change. Thats the best way to learn and get experience.

Comment: true well thanks for your time stefan and thanks for your answer